# Why am I getting the wrong colour here?

Tags: ios, colors, core-graphics, uicolor

The code below results in a pure red square:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0f);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);

}
```

But the code below results in a white square when what I'd expect is a different shade of red.  Can anyone tell me why this is?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor* boxColour = [UIColor colorWithRed:217 green:37 blue:70 alpha:1.0];
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, boxColour.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0f);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` method of the `UIColor` class takes parameters in the range 0.0 to 1.0. You probably just need to divide all the values (except alpha) by `255.0f`:

```
UIColor* boxColour = [UIColor colorWithRed:217/255.0f green:37/255.0f blue:70/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a)